# Procedural wrinkled paper lamp cycles material

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, materials

I am not completely new to Blender, but I'm actually on a project of interior design visualization where I would like to create a material that would allow me turn any surface into this kind of paper lamp.

Its basically wrinkled paper extruding from the volume, never intersecting with each other, slightly opalescent, with a light source inside (which could obviously be another object).

I have no idea where to start from. I guess it should involve procedural material rather that using an image, but I'm not sure how to make the lines protrude neither how to generate them and be able to modify their parameters

I'd be really grateful if someone could show a way into this problem. Cheers!

[image]

Comment: This doesn't look like something that could be realistically simulated with materials alone, this will require some geometry, in fact it may actually need some serious modelling to look good, unless there wont be any closeups and it will only be viewer from afar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, thats what I was fearing. How where could I start with geometry? by drawing geometry and projecting it onto the target surface?

Comment: Yesterday I was playing around with some modifier combinations involving a Decimate + Solidify + Subsurf, and achieved some interesting results but not close enough to the reference picture. Might try again today but won't be able to actually post it here until far later tonight.

Comment: that's very kind of you, take your time

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so here's what I could come up with. This is what I could achieve with **materials only**. Not good enough for closeups, but perhaps enough for far-off objects or to save resources.

[image: Materials Only]

With **modelling** I got to this. It's not perfect, couldn't figure out a way to automatically make them not intersect, but its a reasonable time/effort/fidelity ratio.

[image: Modelling]

Star of with an Icosphere, subdivide it enough, for the desired level of detail, then add a *Decimate* modifier.

[image: Icosphere]

Apply the decimate modifier, enter *Edit Mode* and in *Edge Selection Mode* with the *Random Select* operator select any number of edges around 50% to 60%.

Bevel those edges, then extrude them outwards with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> > *Region (Vertex Normals)*.

[image: Bevel]

[image: Extrude]

Add a *Subsurf* modifier on top, and you are good to go. Material is the same as above without all the texture work.

[image: Subsurf and Material]

Additionally you may use *Proportional Edit* with a *Random* falloff type, to scale all vertex outwards, and/or rotate them slightly, and give it a more irregular look. Use a fake loose vertex, placed at the center of the sphere, selected for scaling, then use the *3D Cursor* as center of transform and increase the influence radius as necessary.

[image: Proportional Edit]